# Use subresource integrity for JavaScript embedded from other domains

Tags: feature-request, security

SE sites require a whole bunch of JavaScript files to work, with most of them served from a different domain than the main Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow domains. Some of these JavaScript files are under the control of other companies like Google. And the main SE JavaScript and CSS files are as far as I understand served by a CDN, which again is a different company than SE.

JavaScript can do a lot of stuff, and if any malicious JavaScript were included on SE sites this might allow an attacker to capture SE accounts and sessions. Especially for moderators and employees this would also potentially compromise the PII these users have access to.

There is a feature called [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) that pretty much any modern browser supports. The basic idea is that in the HTML page you serve you include a hash of the JavaScript files (or other resources) you include via script or link tags. The browser then checks the hash against the file it received from the external domain, and if it doesn't match it doesn't execute it. This prevents any malicious JavaScript from being smuggled into the page by e.g. a compromised CDN or other third party.

Another benefit might be to create much clearer errors for cases where the CDN misbehaves and serves a broken or wrong file. It wouldn't actually help with fixing the error as the browser would block the file entirely, but it would create a clear error message compared to the more subtle breakage that can occur if the CDN serves mismatched or corrupt files.